# How to change the value of meter tag dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I am using one `<meter>` tag in my html5.

I want to change the value of this meter tag dynamically using javascript.

I have used the following:

```
document.form1.meter1.value = 5;
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Some sample code would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
document.getElementById('meter1').setAttribute('value', '0.5');
```

Answer (score 0):

The max value for a meter tag (if you haven't specified it) is `1`. So if you want to change its value it has to be in range form 0 to 1.

So your code is correct, it just doesn't work because the value you're giving it is incorrect. Give it a value of say 0.05 (because that's what it looks like you want. I'm guessing that you assumed it went form 0 to 100. So 5/100 would be 0.05), and it'll work.

[Read the MDN docs on the meter tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/meter).

Comment: Actually, if you use the `min` and `max` attributes, you can specify the range of the meter tag (per the docs you linked to).

Comment: @BryanRoss That's what I said. I said it defaults to 1 if you haven't specified it yourself.