# Creating a dynamic Tank level/meter using html and css

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-shapes

I am currently having problems creating a 'tank gauging system' within my project. I am using MVC and the by using the following markup, I have achieved this:

[image]

by using:

```
#container {
    position:absolute;
    margin:0;
    margin-top:-50px;    
    width:100%;
    padding:0;    
    -moz-perspective: 1000px; /*required to make cylinder shape*/
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
}
#frame {
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    margin-left:5%;
    -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(40%, 60px, 175px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(40%, 60px, 175px); 

}
.strip {
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d
}
.strip div {
    position: fixed;
    background-repeat:repeat;
    border-width: thin 10px;
    color:#ececec;
    vertical-align:central;
    height:130px; /*height and width of tank display*/
    width:12%;
    background-color:rgba(128,128,128,0.99);
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 2px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 2px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;

-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px -35px 20px -37px rgba(0,0,0,0.96);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px -35px 20px -37px rgba(0,0,0,0.96);
box-shadow: inset 0px -35px 20px -37px rgba(0,0,0,0.96);
}
.strip div:before {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    /*Make this lower so any text appears in front*/

    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 50%; /*used for tank level setting*/
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(56,56,56,0.8);



}
.strip .a {

  
     border-top:1px solid black;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(124px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.strip .b {
     border-top:1px solid black;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(15deg) translateZ(124px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(15deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.strip .c {
     border-top:1px solid black;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(30deg) translateZ(124px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(30deg) translateZ(124px);
}

 .strip .c {
    background: rgb(0,0,0) !important; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(128,128,128,1) 1%, rgba(128,128,128,1) 9%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 10%, rgba(128,128,128,1) 11%, rgba(128,128,128,1) 19%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 20%, rgba(128,128,128,1) 21%, rgba(128,128,128,1) 29%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 30%, rgba(128,128,128,1) 31%, rgba(128,128,128,1) 39%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 40%, rgba(128,128,128,1) 41%, rgba(128,128,128,1) 49%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 50%, rgba(128,128,128,1) 51%, rgba(128,128,128,1) 59%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 60%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 60%, rgba(128,128,128,1) 61%, rgba(128,128,128,1) 69%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 70%, rgba(128,128,128,1) 71%, rgba(128,128,128,1) 79%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 80%, rgba(128,128,128,1) 81%, rgba(128,128,128,1) 89%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 90%, rgba(128,128,128,1) 91%, rgba(128,128,128,1) 99%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%)!important; /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(1%,rgba(128,128,128,1)), color-stop(9%,rgba(128,128,128,1)), color-stop(10%,rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(11%,rgba(128,128,128,1)), color-stop(19%,rgba(128,128,128,1)), color-stop(20%,rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(21%,rgba(128,128,128,1)), color-stop(29%,rgba(128,128,128,1)), color-stop(30%,rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(31%,rgba(128,128,128,1)), color-stop(39%,rgba(128,128,128,1)), color-stop(40%,rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(41%,rgba(128,128,128,1)), color-stop(49%,rgba(128,128,128,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(51%,rgba(128,128,128,1)), color-stop(59%,rgba(128,128,128,1)), color-stop(60%,rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(60%,rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(61%,rgba(128,128,128,1)), color-stop(69%,rgba(128,128,128,1)), color-stop(70%,rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(71%,rgba(128,128,128,1)), color-stop(79%,rgba(128,128,128,1)), color-stop(80%,rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(81%,rgba(128,128,128,1)), color-stop(89%,rgba(128,128,128,1)), color-stop(90%,rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(91%,rgba(128,128,128,1)), color-stop(99%,rgba(128,128,128,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,1)))!important; /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 1%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 9%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 10%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 11%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 19%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 20%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 21%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 29%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 30%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 31%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 39%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 40%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 41%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 49%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 50%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 51%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 59%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 60%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 60%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 61%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 69%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 70%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 71%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 79%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 80%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 81%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 89%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 90%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 91%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 99%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%)!important; /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 1%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 9%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 10%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 11%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 19%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 20%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 21%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 29%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 30%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 31%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 39%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 40%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 41%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 49%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 50%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 51%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 59%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 60%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 60%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 61%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 69%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 70%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 71%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 79%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 80%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 81%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 89%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 90%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 91%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 99%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%)!important; /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 1%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 9%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 10%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 11%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 19%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 20%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 21%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 29%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 30%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 31%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 39%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 40%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 41%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 49%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 50%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 51%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 59%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 60%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 60%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 61%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 69%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 70%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 71%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 79%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 80%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 81%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 89%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 90%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 91%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 99%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%)!important; /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 1%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 9%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 10%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 11%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 19%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 20%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 21%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 29%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 30%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 31%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 39%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 40%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 41%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 49%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 50%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 51%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 59%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 60%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 60%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 61%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 69%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 70%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 71%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 79%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 80%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 81%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 89%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 90%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 91%,rgba(128,128,128,1) 99%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%)!important; /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}

.strip .d {
    border-top:1px solid black;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(45deg) translateZ(124px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(45deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.strip .e {
    border-top:1px solid black;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(60deg) translateZ(124px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(60deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.strip .f {
    border-top:1px solid black;
  
    -moz-transform: rotateY(75deg) translateZ(124px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(75deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.strip .g {
    border-top:1px solid black;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(124px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.strip .h {
    border-top:1px solid black;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(105deg) translateZ(124px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(105deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.strip .i {
    border-top:1px solid black;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(120deg) translateZ(124px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(120deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.strip .j {
    border-top:1px solid black;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(135deg) translateZ(124px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(135deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.strip .k {
    border-top:1px solid black;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(150deg) translateZ(124px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(150deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.strip .l {
    border-top:1px solid black;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(165deg) translateZ(124px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(165deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.strip .m {
    border-top:1px solid black;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(124px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.strip .n {
    border-top:1px solid black;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(195deg) translateZ(124px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(195deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.strip .o {
    border-top:1px solid black;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(210deg) translateZ(124px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(210deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.strip .p {
    border-top:1px solid black;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(225deg) translateZ(124px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(225deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.strip .q {
    border-top:1px solid black;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(240deg) translateZ(124px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(240deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.strip .r {
    border-top:1px solid black;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(255deg) translateZ(124px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(255deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.strip .s {
    border-top:1px solid black;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(270deg) translateZ(124px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(270deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.strip .t {
    border-top:1px solid black;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(285deg) translateZ(124px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(285deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.strip .u {
    border-top:1px solid black;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(300deg) translateZ(124px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(300deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.strip .v {
    border-top:1px solid black;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(315deg) translateZ(124px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(315deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.strip .w {
    border-top:1px solid black;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(330deg) translateZ(124px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(330deg) translateZ(124px)
}
.strip .x {
    border-top:1px solid black;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(345deg) translateZ(124px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(345deg) translateZ(124px);

}
```

```html
<div class="tankWidget">
        <div class="banner">Tank 1: Kero</div>
       
        <div id="container">
            <div id="frame">
                <div class="strip">
                    <div id="tank1FrameA"class="a">50%</div>
                    <div class="b"></div>
                    <div class="c"></div>
                    <div class="d"></div>
                    <div class="e"></div>
                    <div class="f"></div>
                    <div class="g"></div>
                    <div class="h"></div>
                    <div class="i"></div>
                    <div class="j"></div>
                    <div class="k"></div>
                    <div class="l"></div>
                    <div class="m"></div>
                    <div class="n"></div>
                    <div class="o"></div>
                    <div class="p"></div>
                    <div class="q"></div>
                    <div class="r"></div>
                    <div class="s"></div>
                    <div class="t"></div>
                    <div class="u"></div>
                    <div class="v"></div>
                    <div class="w"></div>
                    <div class="x"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
   
       

        <div class="widget-footer">
            <table id="specTab1">
                <tr><th>Volume</th><th>Capacity</th><th>Ullage (AL)</th></tr>
                <tr id="tank1"><td id="tank1Vol">50L</td><td>100L</td><td>1.24</td></tr>
            </table>
            <br />
            <div class="lowerWidget-footer">
                <br />
                Details
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

However, I am looking to now make it dynamic. (i.e. the light grey level changes depending on the value within the '.a' strip (in this case 50%).

I was using:

```
        var test = $('#tank1FrameA').text(); //gets value of first tank
        test = parseInt(test);
```

to get the `50` extracted.

However, since I am unable to target the `:before`pseudo element to edit the 'height/level', how else could I achieve this leveling/dynamic ability?

In general;

```
+-------------+
|    50%      | <-- value to use
|             |
+-------------+ <-- this level should change
|             |
|             |
+-------------+
```

for 25%:

```
+-------------+
|    25%      | <-- value to use
|             |
|             |
+-------------+ <-- this level should change
|             |
+-------------+
```

etc etc.

Any suggestions as to how thic can be done with this cylinder shape?

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/x0p7bp8v/1/) is a runnable/editable jsfiddle.

---

## When originally creating

the Tank, I was looking to edit the:

```
.strip div:before {
```

's bottom attribute in order to achieve this.

However, i have recently discovered that pseudo elements aren't part of the DOM, and so are inaccessible to JQuery (powerful as it may be).

Comment: Why don't you use SVG?

Comment: @SPRBRN I'm not quite sure how that will help me in this context?

Comment: How about http://bernii.github.io/gauge.js/ or http://justgage.com/

Comment: @mplungjan i'd rather not include more external libraries, plus I would like to keep the cylinderal shape as it is relevant to the shape of a 'normal' tank

Comment: It won't help you in this context I'm afraid. SVG would mean starting over. It's just a suggestion. The tank would be really round, you can make it interactive with javascript.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you just need to fill the tank, you may use a much simpler stucture to build the tank with two HTML elements, border-radius and a pseudo element.

Then you can use JS to change the height of the green area according to the value entered in the custom data attribute `data-amount` of the `.tk` div :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/orvrzk4w/)** (change the value of the custom data attribute `data-amount` in the `.tk` div to change the height of the liquid).

```js
var amount = $('.tk').attr('data-amount'),
    height = amount * 80/100 + 20;

$('.lq').css({height : height + '%'});
```

```css
.tk{ /*Liquid Section*/
    position:relative;
    width:40%; 
    height:130px;
    padding-top:50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background:rgba(56,56,56,0.8);
    border-radius: 100%/40px;
    border-bottom:3px solid #000;
    text-align:center;
    z-index:1;
    overflow:hidden;

}
.tk:after, .lq{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:0; left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:20%;
    z-index:-1;
}
.lq{
    background:rgba(128,128,128,0.99);
    height:80%;
    top:-2px;
    border-radius:100%/40px;
    border-bottom:3px solid #000;
}
.tk:after{
    height:20%;
    border:1px solid #000;
    border-radius:100%; /*makes circle at top*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tk" data-amount="40">
    40%
    <div class="lq"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/orvrzk4w/3/) so far, but it's still not quite right (10% doesn't *really* work yet. But I applaud your efforts :))

Comment: @jbutler483 Ok this needs calculation so you need to use a custom data attribute see here : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/orvrzk4w/4/ change the values of the `data-amount` to change the height of the liquid in the tank.

Comment: very nice solution. :-) Today using the built in <meter> tag might be more simple ?

Answer (score 1):

Although @web-tiki answer is perfectly good and accepted, I thought I must add another option for simple use-cases.

The following might not have been available or widely adopted at the time of the question, as it involves the HTMl5 tag `</meter>`

If the pseudo-3d effect is not a must, you could use the not-so-known HTML5 built in `<meter>` [element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meter). I have used it occasionally in the past.

basic syntax :

```
<meter id="fuel" name="fuel-so-so"
       min="0" max="100"
       low="33" high="66" optimum="80"
       value="50">
    at 50/100
</mete
```

It is basically designed for such tasks, The only thing that you need to do is to rotate it 90 ( or 270 ) degrees. and for that you could use CSS. ( [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/obmerk99/szp4dwyn/) )

It is also easily [styled](https://css-tricks.com/html5-meter-element/). other examples [here](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/05/30/html5-progress-meter-element/) and [here](https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/style-html5-meter/).

of course it will not produce the same exact effect out-of-the-box ( like the accepted answer ) but I think it is still an option worth mentioning for future users who will bump into this question. ( and with some transparent-png overlay, it can actually be exactly the same.. )

For the JS part, a simple `document.getElementById('fuel').setAttribute('value', myValue);` [should do the trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990813/how-to-change-the-value-of-meter-tag-dynamically).

Another somewhat related SO question with nice fiddle to demonstrate dynamic control : [how to change <meter> values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168992/how-to-change-meter-values)

Answer (score 0):

I think I have achieved the requested, by playing around with positioning (absolute will respect the parent block element with position relative or absolute - so it is easier to just use bottom: 0 - also that makes the div to increase its height from botton to top automatically)

html

```
<div class="tk">
<h3 class="text"></h3>
  <div class="lq" data-amount="69">
    <div class="ring"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css file:

```
.tk {
    position:relative;
    width:40%; 
    height:100px;
    padding-top:40px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background:rgba(56,56,56,0.8);
    border-radius: 100%/40px;
    border-bottom:3px solid #000;
    text-align:center;
    z-index:1;
    overflow:hidden;
    }
    
.lq {
  position: absolute;
  background:rgba(128,128,128,0.99);
  width: 100%;
  height:0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius:100%/40px;
  border-bottom:3px solid #000;
}


.ring {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius:100%;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height:40%;
  content: '';
  border:1px solid #000;
}
    
.text {
  display: block;
  position:absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 45%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

js file (with  jquery):

```
var quantity = amount;
$(this).find('.lq').animate({'height' : parseInt(amount) + '%'},1000);
  $('.ring').css({height : 100 - amount + 10 + '%'});
  $('.text').text(quantity  + '%'); 
  });
  $('.text').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
     jQuery({ Counter: 0 }).animate({ Counter: $this.text() }, {
    duration: 1000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function () {
      $this.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter) + "%");
    }
  });
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DimK10/oqfz56ys/72/